# ASP.NET_SessionID cookie is NOT in the request but shows up in Page_Load()

Tags: asp.net, cookies

In my Page_Load() method of the asp.net webapplication, I have the following:

```
HttpCookie c = Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"];
if (c != null) {
    Label1.Text = "Cookie ASP.NET_SessionId sent by client in the request";
}
```

From all my browsers, I cleared the cache, cookies, etc. and then ran the application and the Label shows that the cookie was found, even though the request header in Fiddler clearly shows that no cookie was sent in the request. There is no way that any cookie was sent because not only is there no cookie called ASP.NET_SessionID in the browser's memory or on hard disk and as I said before, Fiddler clearly shows that no cookie was sent out with the http request.

Fiddler does show that the http response has a Set-Cookie, but that is AFTER the Page_Load() has executed.

So, I am confused as to how the Page_Load() method found the cookie ?

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: maybe is session cookie renamed in web config ? See <system.web>
    <sessionState cookieName="foo" />
</system.web>

Answer (score 1):

The string indexer for the HttpCookieCollection makes a call to the HttpCookieCollection.Get method.  Per [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezy11xy2(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezy11xy2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the Get method will create a cookie with the specified name if the cookie does not already exist.

> If the named cookie does not exist, this method creates a new cookie
>   with that name.

This issue has burned me before!

To check whether a cookie exists without automatically creating it if it doesn't, you can use syntax similar to what I've shown below:

```
bool requestCookieSet = Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(myCookieName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this insted

```
if (Request.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"] != null) {
    Label1.Text = "Cookie ASP.NET_SessionId sent by client in the request";
}
```